# UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight -- flip a group and not just one item

Tags: iphone, uiview

In IB I have 2 UIImageViews, 4 UIText, and 1 TabBar. I want to flip the ImageViews and the Texts together without flipping the TabBar.

I am using:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:ImgViewNameHere cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

When I replace "ImgViewNameHere" with the name of the item, that item flips like I want.

But, I want all 6 items to flip together. Can I group all these items and flip them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place all six views into a container view and then apply the animation to that container.

Comment: I thought of that but I'm not sure how to implement that. I am still new to iphone programming.

Comment: Hmmm, I added another view and moved my 6 elements to that view and then add the new view to the original one. Am I on the right track?

Comment: This seems right but when I drag the new view called "Container" onto the original view called "View" the contents of Container are added to  View and the Container view disappears.

Hmmmm, however, when I save the file in IB.... IT WORKS!!!!!

Thanks